# How to express this recurrence relation as a closed form?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I need a little help with expressing this recurrence relation as a closed form. I've already expanded it out to see the pattern:
$$
f(n) = f\left(\frac{n}{3}\right) + f\left(\frac{2n}{3}\right) + n - 1\\
f(n) = f\left(\frac{n}{9}\right) + 2 f\left(\frac{2n}{9}\right) + f\left(\frac{4n}{9}\right) + 2n - 3\\
f(n) = f\left(\frac{n}{27}\right) + 3 f\left(\frac{2n}{27}\right) + 3 f\left(\frac{4n}{27}\right) + f\left(\frac{8n}{27}\right) + 3n - 7\\
f(n) = f\left(\frac{n}{81}\right) + 4 f\left(\frac{2n}{81}\right) + 6 f\left(\frac{4n}{81}\right) + 4 f\left(\frac{8n}{81}\right) + f\left(\frac{16n}{81}\right) + 4n - 15\\
$$

Obviously the recursive functions have binomial coefficients, the fraction numerators are the powers of 2, the denominators are $3^k$, and the trailing matter is $kn - (2^k - 1)$... but I'm not sure how I can express all that as a closed form solution, in particular the binomial coefficients.

Comment: What do you mean by "closed form?"  Would $f(n) = kn - (2^k-1) + \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}f(2^in/3^k)$ do it?

Comment: If we have $f(n) = 0$ for $n < 1$, this would imply that

Comment: If we have $f(n) = 0$ for $n < 1$, this would indicate that $f(n) \approx n \log(n)/\log(3/2)$. (stupid 5 minute edit rule)

Comment: @martycohen, you can delete your old comments...

Answer (score 0):

$f(n)=f\left(\dfrac{n}{3}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{2n}{3}\right)+n-1$

$f(n)-f\left(\dfrac{n}{3}\right)-f\left(\dfrac{2n}{3}\right)=n-1$

For the particular solution part, getting the close-form solution is not a great problem.

Let $f_p(n)=An\ln n+B$ ,

Then $An\ln n+B-\left(\dfrac{An}{3}\ln\dfrac{n}{3}+B\right)-\left(\dfrac{2An}{3}\ln\dfrac{2n}{3}+B\right)\equiv n-1$

$An\ln n-\dfrac{An}{3}(\ln n-\ln3)-\dfrac{2An}{3}(\ln n+\ln2-\ln3)-B\equiv n-1$

$\dfrac{(3\ln3-2\ln2)An}{3}-B\equiv n-1$

$\therefore\begin{cases}\dfrac{(3\ln3-2\ln2)A}{3}=1\\-B=-1\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}A=\dfrac{3}{3\ln3-2\ln2}\\B=1\end{cases}$

$\therefore f_p(n)=\dfrac{3n\ln n}{3\ln3-2\ln2}+1$

But getting the complementary solution part is not optimistic.

Since we should handle the equation $f_c(n)-f_c\left(\dfrac{n}{3}\right)-f_c\left(\dfrac{2n}{3}\right)=0$ .

$n\to3n$ :

$f_c(3n)-f_c(n)-f_c(2n)=0$

Let $\begin{cases}m=\ln n\\g_c(m)=f_c(n)\end{cases}$ ,

Then $g_c(m+\ln3)-g_c(m)-g_c(m+\ln2)=0$

Which is no hope on how to solve further.